# Code in for loop not executes in Node JS Dialogflow in line Editor

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am new to node js and developing chat bot using Dialogflow.
To get specific response from firebase, I have to call functions as below.

```
  admin.database().ref(institutes+'/'+ Programme).once("value").then((snapshot) => {
        reply= snapshot.val();}).then((reply) =>                                        {
        for (var key in reply)
        {
             console.log('1 executed');
             admin.database().ref(institutes+'/'+ Programme +'/' + key + '/' + 'Group').once("value").then((datagroup)=>
             {
                 if(datagroup.val() == Group)
                 {
                     console.log('2 executed');
                     result+=key;
                 }
             });
        }
  });
  agent.add(`Hello`);
```

Code run successfully with hello message in reply but It is not executing function written inside for loop. i.e. in console there is no messages like 1 executed or 2 executed.

Comment: The question in the current state does not provide adequate information to enable understanding of what the problem may be. Have you checked the logs @ https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/your-project-name/functions/list? The problem definition should be in the logs.

Comment: To use the .once() method to read the data located at your reference, you need to confirm that the child location you have referenced above `(institutes+'/'+ Programme)`exists in your Database.

Answer (score -1):

I recommed you use this example code for contruct your code:

```
function readFromDb (agent) {
    // Get the database collection 'dialogflow' and document 'agent'
    const dialogflowAgentDoc = db.collection('dialogflow').doc('agent');

    // Get the value of 'entry' in the document and send it to the user
    return dialogflowAgentDoc.get().then(doc => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
            agent.add('No data found in the database!');
        } else {
            agent.add(doc.data().entry);
        }

        return Promise.resolve('Read complete');
    }).catch(() => {
        agent.add('Error reading entry from the Firestore database.');
        agent.add('Please add a entry to the database first by saying, "Write <your phrase> to the database"');
    });
}
```

Code taken from [this github file in the `dialogflow/fulfillment-firestore-nodejs` repo](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-firestore-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js)

I used this to make my node.js code for a deploy on firebase. I don't use a for in that but in mi case I need to use a if and this work perfectly.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24863184)

Comment: Thanks for your review, I will have this in mind when I answer another post.